# Vue router, remove hash on some pages

Tags: javascript, hash, vue.js, history, vue-router

I use [vue and vue router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html).

By default it will add `#/` to the urls. I want to have some pages served as PHP and other pages rendered by vue router.

**Examples**

I want all these to work:

- `example.com`
- `example.com/#/some/query/`
- `example.com/about`
- `example.com/about#/some/query/`

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you try to setup a web proxy to redirect request to static file (from vue) and laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, yes - it is possible. But mixing different modes is generally bad idea - it will leads to mess in architecture. Choose history or hash mode and make your application consistent, using just one of them.

Comment: I just found my way out to be consistant with history. Thanks!