# removing hash in a specific page in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

- My task is similar to this
  [Vue router, remove hash on some pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47050786/vue-router-remove-hash-on-some-pages)
- I have to set the hash mode for all but one page: ***mysite.com/success***.
  User is redirected to this page from a external site.
- In this external site installed a redirect to mysite.com/success
  without ***#***. If I set the history mode will show `404` error.

  To do this, you need to configure the server. I do not have access to the server. Any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must to config your HTTP server.

What is your HTTP server? Nginx or Apache?

The vue router have a page explaning how to config with Vue Router with HTTP Servers. See: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Sumary, in your HTTP Server you must redirect the URL mysite.com/success to mysite.com/index.html#success

Comment: I understand that this is more correct, but I do not have access to the server. Is it possible to do without server configuration on the client side?

Comment: Then you must create a file with name `success.html` in root directory. In this file, you can redirect to `index.html` with `window.location`. Or the `success.html` can be a copy of `index.html`

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and this will help others people. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)